# create html form using func_get_arg()

Tags: php

I want to create a form using function that accepts multiple parameters using `func_get_arg()` function. The form should have a drop-down list and submit button, if the form is submitted it should echo back what was selected.

The function is called as follows: `form('choice.php','POST','select car', 'Audi', 'VW', 'Mec', 'Nissan');` I have created the function and I can echo the value in the `func_get_arg`array. how do I associate the values in the array to the form attributes.

```
function form(){

    $showForm = func_get_args();

    //my problem is here

    return $n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you are trying to do.Then you can create a form in html and add drop downs to the form field/s.  Drop down can be hard coded or can be from your database. Code is available.  Then when you will submit the form. The data will be posted using `method='POST'` and you can `echo` what ever you want. If you get what i tried to say and you want to do the same. I can help you with example code

Comment: Thank you for you reply, this is what I am trying to do, form with a single drop-down list that was generated with a function named show_form. This function works with multiple parameters where the number of parameters may vary. That is, the number of options available in the drop-down list depends on the number of parameters.